# DB2 equivalence to Oracle's varchar2(n char)

Tags: oracle11g, db2

i am trying to find a DB2 way to implement the Oracle definition of

varchar2 (n char)

which stores n chars instead of n bytes.

How can this be done in DB2 ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`VARCHAR2(n CODEUNITS32)`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0000927.html) to define such a string.

Db2 allows to use the [VARCHAR2](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.porting.doc/doc/r0052880.html) data type when [Oracle compatibility is enabled](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.porting.doc/doc/r0052867.html). See here for [how to set up Oracle compatibility in Db2](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.porting.doc/doc/t0054729.html). Here is more on [CODEUNITS32 and using byte length or character length](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0008470.html).

Comment: I am still facing the error - SQL0104N An unexpected token "CHAR" was found following

Comment: Have you followed the syntax example in the docs and used CODEUNITS32? What is the full statement you are using? Is the Oracle compatibility turned on? ...?